# Redux/React - Why I can't bind state to this.props on component which is in iframe?

Tags: reactjs, redux, universal

I have a specific scenario in my react/redux/express universal project (server-side rendering).

(1)First I defined my routes like so: [ routes.jsx ]

```
export default (
  <Route component={App} path="/">
    <Route component={MainView} path="main">
      <IndexRoute component={ThemeIndex}></IndexRoute>
    </Route>
    <Route component={AnotherView} path="preview" />
  </Route>
);
```

As you see, when url route is: **localhost:3000/preview**, react-router will use **AnotherView** component.

(2)Now focus on ThemeIndex component: [ ThemeIndex.jsx ]

```
export default class ThemeIndex extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Index</h2>
        <Frame />
        <Control />
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}
```

(3)Frame component like so: [ Frame.jsx ]

```
class Frame extends Component {
  render() {
    const { text, uid } = this.props.infos;
    const themeUrl = `http://localhost:3000/preview?id=${uid}`;
    //console.log('Frame theme:', text);
    //console.log('Frame uid:', uid);
    return (
      <div className="col-md-8 panel panel-default">
        <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 panel-body">
          <iframe src={themeUrl}></iframe>
        </div>
        <div className="details" >
          {text}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => {
    return {
      infos: state.infos
    }
  }
)(Frame);
```

Here I use iframe tag, its src is **http://localhost:3000/preview?id=xxxx**, so it means it will link **AnotherView** component to be iframe's page.

(4)AnotherView Component like so:

```
class AnotherView extends Component {
  render() {
    const { text, uid } = this.props.infos;
    //console.log('AnotherView theme:', text);
    //console.log('AnotherView uid:', uid);
    return (
      <div>
        <div >Another View</div>
        <div>
          {text}
        </div>
        <div>{uid}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => {
    console.log('another view trigger state:', state);
    return {
      infos: state.infos
    }
  }
)(AnotherView);
```

(4)And I have Control component for making dynamic value: [ Component.jsx ]

```
class Control extends Component {
  render(){
    var uid = () => Math.random().toString(34).slice(2);

    return (
        <input
          onChange={(event) => this.props.addTodo({text:event.target.value, uid:uid()})
          />
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => {
    return {
      infos: state.infos
    }
  }
)(Control);
```

(5)List extra files, Action and Reducer:
[ action.js ]

```
export function addTodo (attrs) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    attrs
  };
}
```

[ reducer.js ]

```
export default (state = {text:'', uid:''}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.attrs);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here is Store configuration on server.js:

```js
app.use( (req, res) => {
  console.log('server - reducers:', reducers);

  const location = createLocation(req.url);
  const reducer  = combineReducers({infos: infosReducer});
  const store    = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware)(createStore)(reducer);

  match({ routes, location }, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    
    .......

    function renderView() {
      const createElement = (Component, props) => (
        <Component
          {...props}
          radiumConfig={{ userAgent: req.headers['user-agent'] }}
        />
      );

      const InitialView = (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <RoutingContext
              {...renderProps}
              createElement={createElement} />
          </Provider>
      );

      const componentHTML = renderToString(InitialView);

      const initialState = store.getState();

      ......
```

my application state is like :

```
{
  infos:{
    text: '',
    uid: ''
  }
}
```

(6)Now I key some words on input in Control component. When the input onChange will trigger **addTodo** action function to dispatch action in reducer, finally change the state. In common, the state changing will effect Frame component and AnotherView component, because I used **react-redux** `connect`, bind the state property to `this.props` on the component.

But in fact, there is a problem in **AnotherView** component. in **Frame** component, `console.log` value display the text you key in input correctly. In AnotherView component, even the connect callback will be trigger (`console.log` will print '`another view trigger state: ...`') , the `console.log` in render is `undefined`, like:

```
console.log('AnotherView theme:', text); //return AnotherView theme: undefined
console.log('AnotherView uid:', uid); //return AnotherView uid: undefined
```

I found the main reason: **AnotherView** component is in `iframe`. Because if I remove `iframe`, put AnotherView component directly here, like so:

```
return (
          <div className="col-md-8 panel panel-default">
            <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 panel-body">
              <AnotherView/>
            </div>
            <div className="details" >
              {text}
            </div>
          </div>
);
```

then I can bind `state` properties on `this.props` in **AnotherView** component successfully, then insert `{text}` on JSX html, you can see the value changing real time when you key input value on **Control** component. if I use iframe to link **AnotherView** component be its page, you can't see any changing `{text}` value, because my text default value is empty string value.

How do I bind `state` properties to `this.props` in the component which is in `iframe` when state changing?

**Update**
I can't get the latest `state` in iframe (source is React component), when I changing `state` in another component, and actually the `mapStateToProps` was triggered!(means iframe source component) but its state is not the latest in `mapStateToProps` function. it does not really concerns with the `react-redux` library?

This is the latest state should be in component:
[image]

Below is iframe source component, it can't get the latest state:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load an app in an iframe from a script tag, it will load a separate instance of the app. This is the point of iframes: they isolate code.

Two separate instances of the app won’t “see” updates from each other. It’s like if you open the app in two separate browser tabs. Unless you add some method of communication between them, they will not share state.

It is not clear why you want to render a frame rather than a component directly. But if you really need frames, a simple option would be to use to render the component *into* the frame rather than load a separate app there. You can use a library like [react-frame-component](https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component) for this. Or, simpler, you can just not use frames at all, as it is not clear what purpose they serve. Usually people want them to isolate an app instance but this seems contrary to what you seem to want.

Comment: Thanks your reply, inspire me to find another way to reach my object. I must render in iframe, because I would like to use JSX to be template engine to render template in iframe, I don't want to use another template engine, like jade, handleBar...etc. If I would like to sync iframe state datas, is it possible to pass the latest state in iframe for communication?

Comment: I don’t understand what JSX has to do with iframes. :-(

Comment: If you use something like `react-frame-component`, you will need to remove the `<script>`. Then the *running app* will use iframe as a render target, so there will be no problems with out-of-sync state.

Comment: Hi Dan, please check my total code https://github.com/sevenLee/ServerSideRedux.git ,,,the I used react component to be iframe page (react-router decide), so there is no script tag, just html render by react component.

Comment: I would like to real time change the iframe page by outer component, it is like template generator app. I can define custom style on iframe page (like a theme), that is my real object.